# Added Classes showed in dpm but don't show up in the output HTML

Tags: 7, theming, forms

I want to add some classes into my form (node/add/-- form) so I use hook_form_FORM_ID_alter but I don't know why the classes add to my field in the dpm() output but when I check the html output those classes doesn't show up ?

Here is the code that I have always used for adding a class but I don't know why this doesn't work for this form

```
function contribute_form_alter_form_injection_node_form_alter($form, &$form_state) {

     $form['field_product_brands']['#attributes']['class'][] = 'Added-Class1';
     $form['field_product_brands']['#attributes']['class'][] = 'Added-Class2';
     dpm($form);
}
```

[image]
[image]

I Should mention that I clear the cache and disable and enable the module but no luck.

Comment: For further investigation, please also provide the code snippet that added the classes to your field widget.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given that you try adding classes to a field widget, you might want to use [hook_field_widget_form_alter()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!field!field.api.php/function/hook_field_widget_form_alter/7):

```
/**
 * Implements hook_field_widget_form_alter().
 */
function MYMODULE_field_widget_form_alter(&$element, &$form_state, $context) {
  // Add a css class to widget form elements for all fields of type mytype.
  if ($context['field']['type'] == 'taxonomy_term_reference') {
    // Be sure not to overwrite existing attributes.
    $element['#attributes']['class'][] = 'myclass';
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Mario for your reply. I wanted to change my form and did it in Entity form a lot but  I don't know why it doesn't work on Adding node form for my authenticated users. However your solution solve my problem. Thank you so much